# Woocommerce - Grouped products - Display order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Thanks in advance for helping me out ;)

In woocommerce I have created a grouped product, with lots of sub products

See here [link to site](http://www.fitnessequipmentni.co.uk/main/shop/build-weight-set/)

How can I control the order the grouped products/options are displayed in?

Ideally, I would like it alpabetic if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Missed this info -

If you wish to control the order in which products are shown within a group, edit the “Menu order” option under the “Advanced” section in product data.

RESOLVED. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just set your ordered numbers in Product page > Advanced tab > Menu order of your child products AND also don't forget to set it for your grouped product!

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985838/383847). Instead of `date` you would use `post_title` as outlined in [WP Query Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters). If you don't see any changes you need to clear your transients: `WooCommerce>System Status>Tools>Clear Transients`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_grouped_children_args', 'so_22661392_grouped_children_args' );
function so_22661392_grouped_children_args( $args ){
    $args['orderby'] = 'post_title';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't check before, but i just tested on Woocommerce 3.02 and Menu Order doesn't change the list order in the Group.
As i don't have many products, i deleted and entered the products again in the order i needed because i noticed the ordering was made by date (or #ID)