# How can I sort woocommerce grouped products by post date instead of menu order?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce, hook

What code/filter can I add to my wordpress functions.php file to modify the order of grouped products by post date instead of menu_order? [class-wc-product-grouped.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-product-grouped.php)

```
$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_grouped_children_args', array(
    'post_parent'   => $this->id,
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'fields'        => 'ids',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'numberposts'   => -1,
) );
```

I'm pretty sure you can hook into it but just not sure how to configure the following filter/hook [woocommerce_grouped_children_args](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_grouped_children_args/)

Comment: What you might want to do is `remove_filter` first and do a custom one based on the default woocommerce filter you are trying to override though i think this code of yours should technically work. Maybe do a `var_dump` on the array passed to it and look up its structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you just need to filter the `$args` being passed through the `woocommerce_grouped_children_args` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_grouped_children_args', 'so_29973708_grouped_children_args' );
function so_29973708_grouped_children_args( $args ){
    $args['orderby'] = 'date';
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    return $args;
}
```

If you need help understanding filters, I wrote what I think is a pretty good tutorial on [how to use filters](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/?p=455)

**Update** If you aren't seeing any changes, chances are that the grouped product's children have already been stored in a transient. You will need to delete this transient to see changes right away. You can clear all WooCommerce product transients via the Admin. Navigate to `WooCommerce>System Status>Tools` and click on the button to clear transients.

Comment: Hi Kathy, thanks for helping me better understand how to configure the filter. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work after I added the code snippet you provided to my child theme's functions.php file. Not really sure why but also sent you a separate message on your website after reading your tutorial on how to use filters.

Comment: **Update** clearing the product transients resolved the problem.

Comment: Any ideas since this filter was removed from 3.0?

Comment: @Christina not at the moment. I'm having trouble locating where the group's children are saved/retrieved from the DB.